# Regex problem : match only the first occurence between two terms

Tags: regex

"Received money from SAYLOR SELLY EU S.A.R.L. with reference XXWW025 MENTINUI-NOM  3 654654465/WCX6565223323"
"Card transaction of EUR issued by CaniR* I- CKOUION"
"Card transaction of EUR issued by Suil Flim KL RUIOKE SOR"

**I have these three lines and would match :**

SAYLOR SELLY EU S.A.R.L.
CaniR* I- CKOUION
Suil Flim KL RUIOKE SOR

**I was trying this and select the group 2:**

> (by|from|to)(.*)(with|\")

But it doesn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: What language do you use? What is the exact command that didn't work? How was the result wrong?

Comment: (.*) is greedy, just make it non-greedy by adding ? after * as follows (by|from|to)(.*?)(with|\")

Comment: @Naveed This regex works on regex101. But doesn't work with awk : my_match = match($5,/(by|from|to)(.*?)( with|[\"])/, arr)
my_result = arr[2]

Comment: @Naveed It works for the last two lines, but for the first i get : SAYLOR SELLY EU S.A.R.L. with reference XXWW025 MENTINUI-NOM 3 654654465/WCX6565223323 without the " from the end

Answer (score 1):

As you mention `awk` in you comment, it does not support a non greedy quantifier `.*?`

What you might do is get the longest match first, and then split that match on the last part of the regex again and take the first item.

```
awk '
match($0,/(by |from |to )(.*)( with|")/, a) {
  split(a[2], b, /( with|")/)
  print b[1]
}
' file
```

Output

```
SAYLOR SELLY EU S.A.R.L.
CaniR* I- CKOUION
Suil Flim KL RUIOKE SOR
```